# "Context Information" or "Contextual Information"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

I wrote this sentence

> In our approach we try to use different type of features to
>   build a logical or conceptual structure for the web page. This
>   structure creates a context in which the DOM tree nodes are
>   evaluated and classified. To employ **context information** in the
>   extraction rules, we propose a specific formalism, namely contextual
>   extraction rules.

should it be the "contextual information"?

In general what could be the difference between **context information** and **contextual information**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ask yourself about the *role* of that information.  Does it explain/specify the context itself or does it come from the context and explain some other matter.  If the former, then it's "context information".  If the latter, then contextual.

In general, I believe, information extracted from, and generated/governed by, context, would be contextual.  The information about context would be "context information".  The latter is probably more seldom used.

Comment: Yes, but I don't really think ***context information*** is a very useful collocation, since in most cases it doesn't really convey anything more than just ***context***. And if you wanted to specifically indicate that the primary *purpose* of the "information" was to provide context, you could always refer to it as ***contextualizing information***.